# YouTube API change the Google account

Tags: youtube-api

My company has a YouTube API access with quota extension. This access is linked to the Google account of our previous developper. I would like to transfer this account to another Google account. Is it possible?
Thanks for your help.

Nothing tried yet we are just starting the process.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is for the owner of the account to login and transfer access.

If you are lucky they used a company email account to do it you should be able to reset the password.

Otherwise you will need to create a new project and use that in your app going forward